# Having trouble with python while loop and dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I'm new to python while loop and dictionary.

I want to write a code sample that prompts repeatedly prompts the user for a key followed by a value. The key and value should then be stored in a dictionary.

It should stop prompting the user for keys and values once the user enters the word "Done" as a key followed by "Done" as a value. We may assume that the user will only enter string-type keys and string-type values. We also do not need to worry about duplicate keys.

After the user types "Done" for value and "Done" for key, the code sample should then prompt the user for one lookup key. It will print out the value of that key and finish.

See below for examples...

Example

> Key: Tu
>
> Value: Tuesday
>
> Key: We
>
> Value: Wednesday
>
> Key: Th
>
> Value: Thursday
>
> Key: Fr
>
> Value: Done
>
> Key: Sa
>
> Value: Saturday
>
> Key: Done
>
> Value: Done
>
> What would you like to look up? Fr
>
> Done

**My codes (how to fix it?)**:

```
a = input('Key: ')
b = input('Value: ')
dict = {a: b}
while a != 'Done' and b != 'Done':
        new_dict = {input('Key: '): input('Value: ')}
        dict.update(new_dict)
key = input('What would you like to look up?')
print(dict.get(key))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
d = {}
while True:
    k = input("key: ")
    v = input("value: ")
    d[k] = v
    if k=="Done" and v=="Done":
        break

x = input("What would you like to look up?")

print(d.get(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to fix:

- Define dictionary:

  ```
  d = dict() OR d = {}
  ```
- Set key and value:

  ```
  d[a] = b
  ```
- I'm not sure why would you need another `while` nested loop.

Anyway, here is an example of how you can implement the above definitions:

```
d = dict()
a = raw_input('Key: ')
b = raw_input('Value: ')
d[a] = b
while a != 'Done' and b != 'Done':
    a = raw_input('Key: ')
    b = raw_input('Value: ')
    d[a] = b

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k+":  " + v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get` as the condition for the `while` loop:

```
d = {}
while d.get('Done','') != 'Done':
    key = input('Key: ')
    val = input('Val: ')
    d[key] = val
print(d.get(input("What would you like to look up?:"),"Not present in Dict"))
print("Done")
```

Sample run:

```
Key: Mo

Val: Monday

Key: Tue

Val: Tuesday

Key: Done

Val: Done

What would you like to look up?:Mo
Monday
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code-

```
dict1 = {}
while True:
    a = input('Key: ')
    b = input('Value: ')
    dict1[a] = b
    if a == b == "Done":
        break
key = input('What would you like to look up?\n')
print(dict1[key])
```